# Custom file instead of docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I start to work with a new project using Docker and I can see there is no `docker-compose.yml` file there, but a few files like `docker-compose.myname1.yml`, `docker-compose.myname2.yml` instead. Trying to run `docker-compose up` I get an error:

```
ERROR: 
        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

So I wonder if that's possible for a Docker project to work without the `docker-compose.yml` file and if it is, what conditions should be met. Maybe that's the matter of some specific version or environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/

"Options:
-f, --file FILE             Specify an alternate compose file
(default: docker-compose.yml)"

so in your case that would be:

```
docker-compose  -f dockcer-compose.myname1.yml up
docker-compose  -f dockcer-compose.myname2.yml up
```

Comment: You are right, but with one exception: the working command is `docker-compose -f docker-compose.myname1.yml up`. Anyway thanks, you helped me a lot! :)

Comment: ofcourse, my mistake! Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

There are two different issues presented in your question:

#### The reason for getting an error

1. When running `docker-compose up`, you must be in a directory that contains `docker-compose.yml` (or `'.yaml`), as indicated by the error you are receiving.
2. The reason you are getting an error is either because there is no such file in the current directory, or (less likely) the environment variable `COMPOSE_FILE` is set to something else.

#### Different names for the docker-compose file

In order to use an alternative file, you can take one of these approaches:

1. Run `docker-compose` with the `--file` argument:

```
$ docker-compose --help

  -f, --file FILE     Specify an alternate compose file
                      (default: docker-compose.yml)
```

2. Set the [`COMPOSE_FILE` environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_file) prior to running any `docker-compose` command.